# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

I m getting this code when i want to interact with database.

my web.config contains a connection string that is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="WebNewYearConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=XXXX; Initial Catalog=XXXXX; User ID=XXXXX; Password=XXXXXX;"     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
</system.web>
 <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition Client Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition Client 4.0" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

and my code contains

```
xSqlConnections con = new SqlConnections("System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebNewYearConnectionString"].ConnectionString");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Clientname = Request.QueryString["name"];
        string str = "select * from Client_Detail where Client_Name='" + Clientname + "'";
        DataTable dat;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "tab");
        DataTable dat = new DataTable();
        dat = ds.Tables["tab"];
        EventName.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Event_Name"].ToString();
        Event_Description.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
        Event_Date.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Date"].ToString();
        Entry_Fee.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
        Event_Client.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Client_Name"].ToString();
        Event_Location.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Event_Location"].ToString();
        Session["Event_Name"] = EventName.Text;


    }
```

and my code is giving this error

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

in

***da.Fill(ds, "tab");***

this line

Comment: You havent opened a connection

Answer (score 0):

```
xSqlConnections con = new SqlConnections("System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebNewYearConnectionString"].ConnectionString");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.open();

            string Clientname = Request.QueryString["name"];
            string str = "select * from Client_Detail where Client_Name='" + Clientname + "'";
            DataTable dat;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "tab");
            DataTable dat = new DataTable();
            dat = ds.Tables["tab"];
            EventName.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Event_Name"].ToString();
            Event_Description.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
            Event_Date.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Date"].ToString();
            Entry_Fee.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
            Event_Client.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Client_Name"].ToString();
            Event_Location.Text = dat.Rows[0]["Event_Location"].ToString();
            Session["Event_Name"] = EventName.Text;

            con.Close();
        }
```

*** EDIT ***

If this has resolved the issue, you need to double check your connection string as it isn't resolving correctly.

An easy way to do this is to go to Server Explorer in VS Studio and manually add a connection to your Database. Test the connection to see if it resolves. If it does, you can copy the connection string from the properties tab for the data connection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: See my Edit. use VS Studio  Server Explorer to get connection string value.

Answer (score 0):

Are there actually quotes around the whole thing in your code?  If so then that is your problem.

```
xSqlConnections con = new SqlConnections("System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebNewYearConnectionString"].ConnectionString");
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection instance like this:

```
xSqlConnections con = new SqlConnections(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebNewYearConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```